# Vue/Vuex watcher dynamic/async component loading

Tags: asynchronous, vuejs2, vuex

I have a base component within which I have a dynamic component with a v-for that displays based on a computed property.

All I've really tried doing thus far, which was an incorrect methodology, was to wrap the method that loads data in a settimeout.  This question is as much a methodology question as it is a coding question.

My base component looks like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-progress-linear
      v-model="progressValue"
      v-if="loading"
    ></v-progress-linear>
    <component
      v-for="table in tables"
      :key="table.id"
      :is="table.structure"
      :table="table"
    ></component>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
  import Annual from './DataTables/Annual';
  import { mapState, mapGetters } from 'vuex';
  export default {
    name: "Page",
    props: [],
    components: {
      Annual,
    },
    data: () => ({
      progressValue: 0,
      loading: false,
      tables: [],
    }),
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters({
        currentTables: 'getCurrentPageTables',
        tableTitles: 'getCurrentPageTableTitles',
      }),
      ...mapState({
        pageName: state => state.pageName,
        snakeName: state => state.snakeName,
      }),
    methods: {
      updateTables(payload) {
        this.loading = true;
        payload.forEach(title => {
            this.tables.push(this.currentTables.filter(e => title === e.name)[0]);
            this.progressValue = this.tables.length / payload.length;
          })
      },
    },
    watch: {
      snakeName: {
        handler() {
          this.progressValue = 0;
          this.updateTables(this.tableTitles);
          this.$nextTick(() => {this.loading = false;})
        },
        immediate: true,
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

Annual.vue is simply a component that displays a Vuetify v-data-table element and its structure is fairly inconsequential to this.

For all intents and purposes we can consider currentTables and tableTitles to both be arrays, the first of objects whose data populate the v-data-tables in Annual.vue, and the second of strings which are just the names of the tables.

When the user navigates to another page the getters return different data, based on the page the user navigates to, but some of the pages have over 20 tables, which makes page loading slow upon navigation to these pages.  I am trying to do one of two things:
1. Asynchronously load the components one at a time while still making the page functional for the user to navigate through.
2. Display a loader that disappears after all of the content is rendered.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to do the latter because I can't put this functionality into the mounted() hook since all of this happens upon the watched parameter changing (hence the component is not re-mounted each time the route changes).

Any advice on how to tackle this would be appreciated.

Comment: In your `v-for` you are iterating over the `tables` array in your `data` object by saying `in tables`, but you never inject any data into `tables`.

Comment: It's done within the updateTables method

Comment: ahh I see, I think you can just iterate over `currentTables` getter like `table in currentTables` and then in the syntax interpolate the html like `<p> {{table.title}} </p>` for example

Comment: Also the reason I have a separate method instead of just assigning tables to equal currentTables is because I have other components that give the user the option to only display some of the tables, but that option doesn't matter for this issue.

Comment: I don't think you can use a computed property in a method. Computed properties no longer have reactivity once computed. If you need to filter you would do the filtering within the vuex getter.

Comment: I appreciate that but the issue isn't one of reactivity. I just want to either load the tables one by one or (more likely) just have a loader display when the watcher is triggered and somehow track when all of the components and data have loaded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193906/discussion-between-jeff-and-lenjoseph).